# Directly editing a value in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Could someone please explain how I can simply dynamically edit a cell in a gridview. i.e. Just click on it and type, and post the changes when I lose focus to the gridview?

I have tried defining a cell as a template control (textbox) and get it to display and let me type in, but it does nothing beyond that. I cannpt even get the default value from the underlying dataset into that cell.

ASP 2.0 and VB.NET please.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id"
        ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="4" AllowSorting="True" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Id">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" ShowHeader="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="QuantityTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnNew" runat="server" CommandName="New" Text="New" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Set the editable property and then use the events of grid

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        String StudentId = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        String Firstname = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
        String Lastname = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text;
        String Email = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(StudentId);
        Response.Write(StudentId);
        try
        {
            studentEntities context = new studentEntities();
            tbl_Students dbstudent = context.tbl_Students.First(i => i.Studentid == id);
            dbstudent.Firstname = Firstname;
            dbstudent.Lastname = Lastname;
            dbstudent.Email = Email;
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e1.InnerException);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a TemplateField rather than a BoundField. In the TemplateField put a TextBox. (Or a check box or whatever you need.) Put an "update" button somewhere on the screen. For example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="mydata" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsMydata" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Noneditablefield" HeaderText="Non-editable field" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Editable Field">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="myfield" runat="server" Columns="10" text='<%# eval("myfield") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then create a function to handle the update button click. In this function, loop through the rows of the table, use FindControl to get the field, and do whatever you need to do with it.

```
Protected Sub update_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles update.Click
  For Each row As GridViewRow In tasks.Rows
    Dim MyField = CType(row.FindControl("myfield"), TextBox).Text
    ' Do whatever you need with the new value
  End For
End Sub
```

Assuming there are multiple rows, some of the rows will be updated and some not. Depending on the nature of your app, you may just update all rows, changed or not. I've done this when I'm feeling lazy and I know there are only a few records and there's not a big issue of two users looking at the same data and making changes concurrently. More likely, though, you want to save the old values, for example in a hidden field in the gridview, and then on return compare the new value to the old value and only update the db if changed.

Comment: Old post I know, but this was hella useful. Just had to convert the VB to C#. Thank you

Comment: A thought comes to mind, however. You really shouldn't have duplicate `id`'s in the same html page, is there a way to use the `FindControl` method by class instead?

Comment: They're not really duplicate IDs. The "real" ID, the ID you see if you view source, is not the same as the ID you see in the VB (or C# or whatever) code. ASP.NET mangles the ID to insure it's unique, exactly for cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new `GridView` to the page and, from its `Smart Tag`, click the `Enable Editing`

For more information on how to do this you can look from here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

you need to add your own controls into template fields instead of bound fields,capture this event within gridvew and update your row accordingly.

Something you can start like this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = TryCast(e.CommandSource, Button)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = TryCast(btn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

    If row IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim txt As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
        If txt IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Do something here 
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I mentoned - I want to directly edit the cell WITHOUT clicking an Edit hyperlink first. Directly Access the cells toi update the data.

Comment: @AndrewMcLintock-Updated answer.